# Windows Service Status C++?

Tags: c++, windows, service, status

How I can get the status of an windows service in C++?

This is a C# example:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("Spooler", "Server1");
if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The service is running.");
}
```

But how do I do the equivalent in C++?

Answer (score 7):

You need to call [`OpenSCManager()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684323%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), then [`OpenService()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684330%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and then [`QueryServiceStatus()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685996%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get the status.

When you're done call [`CloseServiceHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682028%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) twice, once on the service handle, and then on the handle returned by `OpenSCManager()`.

Comment: @Rhino The MSDN documentation for each Win32 function tells you, for each function, what include file you need to use. Read down the page to the section headed Requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about `CloseServiceHandle`. Here's a code sample that does basically does what this answer describes, except it only checks to see if it's running (which should be easy enough to update for custom purposes): https://gist.github.com/the-nose-knows/607dba810fa7fc1db761e4f0ad1fe464 -- @Rhino