# How do I determine if Windows Credentials are disabled

Tags: security, winapi, credentials, credential-manager

I am using the `CredRead()` and `CredWrite()` functions from the Windows Credential Manager API to store and retrieve user passwords, as outlined in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9228105/2407350).

However, I have read that it is possible to disable the Credential Manager by setting a Group Policy, or simply by stopping/disabling the Credential Manager service.  In this case, I would like to update my application's UI to reflect that Credential storage is not currently available.

Is there a reliable way to determine programmably whether or not the Credential Manager has been disabled?

Comment: What happens to the API functions when you apply the policy? Do they fail with a specific error?

Comment: `Cred*` api worked even with disabled Credential Manager service - independ from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in windows exist *VaultSvc* (friendly name *Credentials Service*) which support different vault types. exist util `VaultCmd.exe` with which we can enumerate different credential schemas and loaded vaults. for example:

```
vaultcmd /listschema
Global Schemas

Credential schema: Windows Secure Note
Schema guid: 2F1A6504-0641-44CF-8BB5-3612D865F2E5

Credential schema: Windows Web Password Credential
Schema guid: 3CCD5499-87A8-4B10-A215-608888DD3B55

Credential schema: Windows Credential Picker Protector
Schema guid: 154E23D0-C644-4E6F-8CE6-5069272F999F

Currently loaded credentials schemas:

Vault: Web Credentials
Vault Guid:4BF4C442-9B8A-41A0-B380-DD4A704DDB28

Credential schema: Windows Web Password Credential
Schema guid: 3CCD5499-87A8-4B10-A215-608888DD3B55

Vault: Windows Credentials
Vault Guid:77BC582B-F0A6-4E15-4E80-61736B6F3B29

Credential schema: Windows Domain Certificate Credential
Schema guid: E69D7838-91B5-4FC9-89D5-230D4D4CC2BC

Credential schema: Windows Domain Password Credential
Schema guid: 3E0E35BE-1B77-43E7-B873-AED901B6275B

Credential schema: Windows Extended Credential
Schema guid: 3C886FF3-2669-4AA2-A8FB-3F6759A77548
```

and

```
vaultcmd /list
Currently loaded vaults:
        Vault: Web Credentials
        Vault Guid:4BF4C442-9B8A-41A0-B380-DD4A704DDB28
        Location: C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Vault\4BF4C442-9B8A-41A0-B380-DD4A704DDB28

        Vault: Windows Credentials
        Vault Guid:77BC582B-F0A6-4E15-4E80-61736B6F3B29
        Location: C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Vault
```

of course *vaultcmd* and most vaults, say *Web Credentials* (store passwords in ie) will be work only in case *VaultSvc* is running

but **Windows Credentials** (*77BC582B-F0A6-4E15-4E80-61736B6F3B29*) is built in credential, which is always running (inside lsass), even if  *VaultSvc* not running (disabled). the `CredRead`, `CredWrite`, `CredEnumerate`, and other `Cred*` api will be always work. it can not be disabled

---

exist undocumented api `Vault*` api implemented in `vaultcli.dll`. all this api named in form `Vault*`. when we call it and in case *VaultSvc* is running - `vaultsvc.dll` is loaded in lsass and handled remote call :

```
vaultcli!VaultSomeApi -> rpc - > vaultsvc!VltSomeApi
```

for example when we call `VaultEnumerateItems` in client, `VltEnumerateItems` called in lsass (vaultsvc.dll). what is internally called inside `VltEnumerateItems` depend from concrete vault, on which it called. for *Windows Credentials* vault - `CredEnumerateW` called inside `VltEnumerateItems`

Answer (score -1):

The name of the Credentials Service is **[VaultSvc](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/what-is-the-credential-manager-vaultsvc-service/)**.
You can find how to query the status of any service in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808085/how-to-get-the-status-of-a-service-programmatically-running-stopped) answer and just use the code whilst passing the "ValutSvc" string to the function.

Comment: I don't know precisely how lsass.exe manages credentials across Windows versions, with or without VaultSvc (vaultsvc.dll). However, I can say that in Windows 10 a clean boot with this service disabled does not completely disable the Credential Manager API. The remote procedure call is still handled by LSA. For example, I was able to enumerate a user's stored credentials via `CredEnumerate`, which triggered a breakpoint set on `lsasrv!CredrEnumerate` in lsass.exe. Also, I was able to write new credentials via `CredWrite`, which triggered a breakpoint set on `lsasrv!CredrWrite` in lsass.exe.

Comment: I understand my answer may be incomplete and I will research further and update it. I find the question very interesting...